# Creating a captioned figure, but with a place exactly where I put it

Tags: floats

So I'm trying to add figures and I've tried few codes.

I liked the results that I get with

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{img/imgfile}
\end{center}
```

But

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{img/imgfile}
\caption{somecaption}
\end{figure}
```

Enables me to add a caption.

However the latter one also seems to place the figure at the start of the page, rather than to the location, where the `\includegraphics` command is located.

I need to control, where the figure is placed, rather than have it placed automatically.

I also need captions.

---

Or is it reasonable that figures would always be placed on top of the page. I'm writing an academic text.

Comment: It's reasonable that figures are always on top or bottom of the page. I think it's quite ugly to have a picture or table breaking up the flow of the text. As long as you don't have the picture many pages away, I think it's best to let LaTeX handle those positioning. Having the floats at start or end of the page or a dedicated page is way more elegant and effective.

Comment: @Moriambar: I don't think this is an absolute rule. One may have very good reasons to want a figure at a precise place.

Comment: Use `\captionof{figure}{Your caption text}` from the `caption` or `capt-of` packages.

Comment: @Bernard no rule is absolute. But it's a good guideline.

Comment: @Bernard only for completeness: If you're using a KOMA-class, you don't need the `caption` or `capt-of`-packages, a KOMA-script has the `\captionof` command built in.